# Analytics event tracking on recaptcha attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, recaptcha

I have received feedback that my google reCAPTCHA has not been functioning for some people. I've never had any problems myself but I don't like the idea of people not being able to submit a contact form...

I'd like to set up a google analytics event to see how many people are attempting the recaptcha and compare that to actual form submissions to see if there is a large discrepancy.

I've tried targeting a click event on the reCAPTCHA tickbox component:

```
$('.g-recaptcha-container').click(function(event){
    console.log('checkmark!');
  });
```

but (I think) because the reCAPTCHA widget is inside an `iframe` I think I haven't been able to target click events on any of the DOM inside the widget.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest...the more I think about this...you probably aren't going to be able to do this because the iframe is cross origin... I wasn't even thinking about that because I've been busy...I was thinking they were in the same domain...but if you're trying to grab something in a cross-origin iframe...it's not going to work...sorry about that.

Comment: Cheers, but this didn't work for me. It's like the reCAPTCHA element is its own contained piece of DOM and I can't seem to target elements within it for some reason.

Comment: what's the tag look like for the recaptcha iframe `<iframe class="?" id="?">` etc? Because if it doesn't have the class `.g-recaptcha-container`...then yeah...this won't work...but there may be another way to target it. Also, this should be placed in a document.ready function or loaded at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The iframe itself doesn't have a class or id. But the div it is inside has classname `g-recaptcha`. I've tried targeting that and no joy. Code is placed inside a `document.ready` function. I noticed that the recpatcha element loads a bit after the rest of the page has loaded so I tried running your suggested code inside a `setTimeout()` function so that it runs 5 seconds or so after page has loaded by which time the recaptcha has well and truly loaded - still no joy.

Comment: Thanks for your effort anyway Kevin. At  least I learnt something about cross origin elements... :-) Still, there must be a way to do this. Surely the DOM within the iframe isn't completely out of reach.